# Using Node JS built-in function for Chrome Extension

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension. I have a background script and a content script. They are mainly communicating with each other, but at one point I need to run a shell command line automatically and get the response. After searching, I found the function execSync from child_process in node, and tried to use it with:
`const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;`

But as I ran the program, I got an error saying that this is not a function. I tried to replace it with import instead of require, and I got an error while compiling it saying that this is not a module.

After searching for a while, I found things like Browserify, but I feel like they only work for npm-packages and not for node functions.

i'm actually a beginner, and started (mostly) js with this project, and I don't know much about how Node JS works and what it is like, so this may be a stupid error.

I tried building a npm project with running npm init and putting all of my files in there, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Extensions can use [nativeMessaging](https://3-72-0-dot-chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: If I understand it well, that requires to have another app running, which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: It's the only method.